# adding rows vs creating new tables

Tags: mysql

I am having a table where I have not more than 15 columns (maximum data type of any of those column is SMALL INT and only a single column of type VARCHAR with maximum 20 chars only). Out of those 15 columns one column is Id of data type TINYINT. And there are maximum 50 rows possible against this Id. And maximum 25 Ids are possible.

Here is one such possible example (I have reduced the number of rows and columns in the example)

```
+----+----------+-------+    
| Id | Name     | Subject |    
+----+----------+-------+    
|  1 | Sam      | Maths   |    
|  1 | Sam      | Bio     |   
|  1 | Sam      | Phy     |    
|  2 | Taylor   | Bio     |   
+----+----------+-------+
```

My questions are

1. Should I prepare a single table for all the Ids (resulting almost 1250 rows in one table) or should I go for a single table for each id (not more than 50 rows in one table)?
2. What if number of rows reduced from 50 to 30 against an Id?
3. What if number of rows increased from 50 to 100 against an Id?
4. What if number of Ids increased from 25 to 50 with same 50 number rows against an Id?

The thing is if I prepare a single table `inserting/updating/deleting` (e.g. a subject or Name)  will be easy but if I prepare too many tables `inserting/updating/deleting` will be difficult somewhat.

Comment: 1. Option A. 2. So what? 3. So what? 4. So what?

Comment: oO you have a tinyint id field which has duplicates? not wanting to sound rude or something but an "id" field should never have duplicates at all. Datawise it looks like you are showing an in between table between student and subject (as example)

Comment: As per the logic, if you don't have repetition of data, it should have single data table

Comment: What if what? When you reduce from 50 to 30 then you have 30. What's the question? Anyway, it seems you have not really a clue how databases are used (no offense), maybe some excel tables are better suited for you. If you think otherwise, I think you should read about database normalization.

Comment: Also as not clear from my comment: Why tinyint and not int?

Comment: I didnt get what u are asking @Strawberry

Comment: I think fancyPants has captured the mood.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for d reply its just an example; u can consider the id as int also in case u have answer for d questions

Comment: Hi @Ankur140290 but here id is repeating may be for possible 50 rows against a single id

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg If max no of data is repetitive, then i would suggest to create a new table and shift the data to new table. But for the example you have added, I can't think any need for second table. Eg. say you have a table as: ID, Name, address1, address2,address3, Country, Hobies. and 1 person can have multiple address, then shift address in new table.

Comment: hi @fancyPants It seems that I did not post the question clearly. And you are correct I am prodigy in using databases. If I change the rows to 30 the size of table is reduced for 25 ids from 1250 rows to 750 rows (if a single table for all ids is the answer)

Comment: Hi @Ankur140290 thanks again for the reply. Yes maximum data is repeating but the think is if for each id I prepare a new table the insert/delete/update a entry will be required to perform on all tables. It seems to be hectic then. The example is just for the sake to clear my questions I already said in question the number of columns are almost 15 rows will vary in between 30 to 50

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg Doesn't really matter. 1250 rows is a joke for a database (if setup properly). I'm handling tables here that have several hundreds of millions of rows, not joking, that's 123.456.789 rows and I'm sure others deal with much more data. But, like I said, it seems the way you store your data is just wrong. This is no easy task. Maybe the wikipedia article of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a good start to at least understand what you're dealing with. And also like I said, maybe other forms of storing your data is better suited for your needs

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg I know that this will be hectic task. But as per normalization, you should break your db as much possible. This will reduce the size of your db and you will touch limited no of tables at a given time (assuming you don't require to update each data every time)

Comment: @fancyPants thanks for the reply. Im working on a light weight real time embedded system and I already said I am newbie in databases so I am not handling so much of data that u are handling. I know that database normalization is the step to reduce the data redundancy and make the tables effective. It seems that stackoverflow is for advanced developers and experts only from ur suggestions. Any way thanks for ur reply

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg a few here are just a bit (too) direct when telling someone where possible problems are or where solutions are. but normally everyone means good regardless if someone is new or experienced. What ankur, fancy,... pointed out about normalization though is not only good for big databases. Even with only a few dozens or hundreds entry it can help save your behind a few times. It normally ends in some sql statements being then easier to implement than otherwise and also in environments like embedded ones that you use less resources for a specific statement than otherwise.

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg For embedded systems MySQL is not the right choice anyway. Try sqlite.

Comment: @fancyPants does it not work with embedded systems? or are there other problems? (long time since I last had something to do with embedded systems)

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg only see this here as a note though. Most of the time you have pure database specific questions there is a subsite on stackexchange just for this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/  if it is about administration things for example. (only meant as a comment as I myself overlooked that sites existence for years^^')

Comment: @Thomas I'm not familiar with sqlite or embedded systems. Just happen to know that usually sqlite is used on embedded systems cause it's less resource hungry.

Comment: @fancyPants ah tnx. a less resource hungry is quite a big argument for embedded as far as I'm aware. Good to know. tnx!

Comment: @fancyPants thanks for the reply. Sqlite do not support simultaneous concurrent write operation which my application needs.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for ur kind reply. Its just that I felt so I replied. Sry for being somewhat arrogant will definitely look for the database normalization. But as I already said from the documentation only normalization should be the next step to reduce data redundancy. Currently I want to get things working asap and was unable to freeze out with tables so I asked the questions.

Comment: Hi @Ankur140290 again, currently I revised my table columns from 10 to 7 out of those 7 columns 2 columns are forming a composite foreign key. In this case is it good to prepare a new table for 5 or 6 rows? Only one column value (can consider id from the example here) is repeating in this case which is also a foreign key referring to another primary key element of another table. Thanks to primary and foreign key constraint ( cascade update and delete ) at least it solved update and delete problem. Now only I am worried @ insert if multiple small tables are prepared. Kindly revert back.

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg I think you can create new table.